# Accessing HTTP POST data from Bottle Server

Tags: python, json, http, post, bottle

I have a simple python http listening server as shown below.

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/',method='POST')
def default():
    return 'My first bottle program.'

run(host='192.168.132.125', port=1729)
```

If I do a POST of some data (a JSON file) from another server as follows

```
curl -X POST -d @data_100 http://192.168.132.125:1729/
```

I get the output

```
My First Bottle Program
```

Now I want my Bottle server to dump the contents of the posted JSON file to a folder on the server.How can I achieve this.

Comment: There's documentation on accessing form data here: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#html-form-handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at Bottle's [built-in json property](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.json).

With no error checking, it'd look something like this:

```
@route('/', method='POST')
def default():
    json_text = request.json
    with open('/path/to/file', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(json_text)
    return 'My first bottle program.'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access posted form data with request.forms object.
And then parse/dump/do_anything with standard python tools.

You can read about FormDict and his methods here:
http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.FormsDict